# Automate running script as a different user on remote server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh

I can run a script on remote a server with command:
`ssh user1@ip-of-server "command"`

That works fine but I need to execute a command with a different user (user2). 
If I do it manually - these would be the steps:
1) SSH as user1 to a server
2) `sudo su - user2` 
3) execute command (now as user2)

What is the best way to automate this? Should I ssh as user2 to a server or there is a way to ssh as user1, switch to user2 and execute command?

Thanks.

Comment: probably you run the script as soon as you login to user2 https://askubuntu.com/questions/704768/run-script-on-login-script-with-sudo-or-startup

Comment: So the problem is that I need to trigger execution from my local server. If I try to login as user1 and then send command (via SSH) to switch to user2 `sudo su - user2` - it just fails (but I can do it manually by first ssh-ing to a server as user1 and then switching to user2). I just want to automate all steps so that can execute all from my local server.

Comment: Or alternatively you can use sshpass -p pwd ssh user2@192.168.x.xxx '<command to execute>'

Comment: I am wondering why you are not trying ssh as user2. Anyway you can run command like `ssh user1@server-ip "sudo su user2 -c 'command'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ssh in, you can execute commands as you say like:

```
ssh user@server command
```

You can also execute multiple commands like such:

```
ssh user@server 'command1; command2; command3;'
```

In order to perform an action as another user in a script, you (ideally) need to enable passwordless sudo, which is detailed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux).

But as a TLDR, you need to put the following in your /etc/sudoers file:

```
ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I cannot recommend doing exactly that, but and that you follow the instructions that I linked too for finer control.

Once you have passwordless sudo, you can then do the following:

```
ssh user@server 'sudo -u user2 "whoami"'
```

That command will return `user2`.

Comment: Yes, this works. But I need to execute e.g. `command2` as `user2` - that is a key point.